# SweetAlert2 pop up didn't show when button clicked, Laravel10, $ is not defined when the page inspected

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, laravel-blade, sweetalert2

I installed SweetAlert2 to my Laravel project using this two tutorial: https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-install-sweetalert2-in-laravel-10-viteexample.html and https://shouts.dev/articles/laravel-10-how-to-implement-sweet-alert , however, SweetAlert2 usual popup 'yes/no' didn't show up. When the page is inspected, get error of **'Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined'** .

Here's source code that related to SweetAlert2 in my Laravel project

**resources/js/app.js**

```
import jQuery from 'jquery';
window.$ = jQuery;
  
import swal from 'sweetalert2';
window.swal = swal;

import './bootstrap';
// For scanning function
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#scanner').val('');  // Input field should be empty on page load
    $('#scanner').focus();  // Input field should be focused on page load 

    $('html').on('click', function () {
        $('#scanner').focus();  // Input field should be focused again if you click anywhere
    });

    $('html').on('blur', function () {
        $('#scanner').focus();  // Input field should be focused again if you blur
    });

    $('#scanner').change(function () {

        if ($('#scanner').val() == '') {
            return;  // Do nothing if input field is empty
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: '/scan/save',
            cache: false,
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                user_id: $('#scanner').val()
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $('#scanner').val('');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**vite.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/sass/app.scss',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            $: 'jQuery'
        },
    },
});
```

**resources/views/dash.blade.php**

```
<head>  
        <title>@yield('title')</title>
        @vite(['resources/sass/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.js'])
        @include('partials.dashHead')
    </head>
```

**resources/views/admin/rent/index.blade.php**

```
<form action="{{ route('rent.destroy',$row['id']) }}" method="Post">
                                <a class="btn btn-primary show-alert-approve-box" data-toggle="tooltip" title='approve' href="{{ route('rent.approve',$row['id']) }}">Terima</a>
                                @csrf
                                @method('DELETE')
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger show-alert-delete-box" data-toggle="tooltip" title='Delete'>Tolak</button>
                            </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('click', '.show-alert-delete-box', function(event){
            var form =  $(this).closest("form");

            event.preventDefault();
            swal({
                title: "Are you sure you want to delete this record?",
                text: "If you delete this, it will be gone forever.",
                icon: "warning",
                type: "warning",
                buttons: ["Cancel","Yes!"],
                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
            }).then((willDelete) => {
                if (willDelete) {
                    form.submit();
                }
            });
        });
        $(document).on('click', '.show-alert-approve-box', function(event){
            var form =  $(this).closest("form");

            event.preventDefault();
            swal({
                title: "Are you sure you want to approve this record?",
                text: "Update this data into approval",
                icon: "warning",
                type: "warning",
                buttons: ["Cancel","Yes!"],
                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                confirmButtonText: 'Yes, approve it!'
            }).then((willDelete) => {
                if (willDelete) {
                    form.submit();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Is there something wrong with my code that made SweetAlert2 pop up didn't appear? or I must resolve **'$ is not defined'** first?